# Script not reading JSON result - Facebook Graph API

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, csv, facebook-graph-api

**Background** - I am trying to export 100 comments from a public Facebook post using Graph API and `json2code` (a npm package). The issue I am having is trying to get NodeJS to read the file as when running the code I get a blank (empty) result.

```
var json2csv = require('json2csv');
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var graph = require('fbgraph'); 

// Settings
var accessToken = 'xxx';
var limitCount = 100;
var postID = 'xxxxxxxx';
var fields = ['data.from.name', 'data.message', 'data.like_count', 'data.from.id', 'data.created_time'];

// API
var fbGraph = `https://graph.facebook.com/${postID}/comments?limit=${limitCount}&access_token=${accessToken}`;

console.log(fbGraph);

request({
    url: url,
    method: "GET",
    timeout: 100000,
    json: true
}, function (error, response, body) {

    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        console.log(body) // Print the json response
    }
});
var csv = json2csv({ data: fbGraph, fields: fields });
console.log(csv);

fs.writeFile('exports/export.csv', csv, function(err) {
 if (err) throw err;
 console.log('File successfully exported!');
});
```

The `console.log(fbGraph);` outputs exactly what I need, here is an example of its result when I paste it into my browser:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "created_time": "2017-04-07T00:49:05+0000",
         "from": {
            "name": "xxxxx",
            "id": "xxxxxx"
         },
         "message": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
         "can_remove": false,
         "like_count": 22,
         "message_tags": [
            {
               "id": "xxxx",
               "length": 7,
               "name": "xxxx",
               "offset": 62,
               "type": "page"
            },
            {
               "id": "xxxx",
               "length": 10,
               "name": "xxxx",
               "offset": 214,
               "type": "page"
            }
         ],
         "user_likes": false,
         "id": "xxx"
      }
   ],
   "paging": {
      "cursors": {
         "before": "xxxx",
         "after": "xxxx"
      },
      "next": "xxxx"
   }
}
```

*Names and personal information were removed to protect privacy*

As you already may see I am looking to capture the following (in order) in csv format:

> - data -> from -> name
> - data -> message
> - data -> like_count
> - data -> from -> id
> - data -> created_time

When I run the script, it shows the field names in the CSV file but the data I am trying to grab from Facebook does not appear. If I was to use this script with in-line JSON inside a variable, it works successfully.

Am I doing something wrong? I am fairly new to Javascript so correct me if a process that I am using can be done more efficiently as well.

**EDIT**: Might possibly be due to not parsing it?
**EDIT 2**: I've edited the code to add the HTTP request via a npm package and I am still having troubles!

Comment: The code does not seem to make any HTTP request to retrieve the data. Your browser makes one for you when entering the URL in the address bar, you have to make in yourself in the code.

Comment: @J.N. Makes sense, how would I go about doing so?

Comment: https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/HTTP/clients/how-to-create-a-HTTP-request/

Comment: @J.N. Thanks for that, I will have a read :)

Comment: Looks like json2csv takes an array of objects, your passing an object (that has an array). Try calling: `json2csv({ data: fbGraph.data, fields: fields })` and remove `data.` from the fields. https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv

Comment: @Lachie - your welcome :)